# Disable chrome as multi process.Chrome version 68 not able to capture the URL

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, windows-7

I have installed the chrome 68 on my machine. windows 7 as OS. I have application called pace to monitor the user activity when user browse the url from chrome.

My application calculate the productive hours and non productive hours, but when i show in grid title and URL which user visited the url is not getting captured.

But in case of version 67 of chrome my app is working fine and capturing the URL fine and it is working fine in IE11.

Is there any property in version 68 which blocks the capturing of the URL in windows 7. Is there any flag which stops it. Please let me know aspa.

I m using this code

```
AutomationElement elementx = element.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, conditions);

string url = ((ValuePattern)elementx.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern)).Current.Value as string;"
```

to find the first tab.

As all the tabs are active as per chrome new version that is 68. So it get confused which one is the active tab. As there is change related to chrome in terms of process. Now it creates separate process for tabs. How can i disable the multi process property or setting or flag in chrome. Or how can i fix the issue related to chrome 68, as it was working fine in version 67. how can i make the chrome single process. To find active tab in chrome 68 version.

Comment: *"Is there any property in version 68 which blocks the capturing of the URL"* Hopefully.

Comment: I also don't know about the property or flag which is blocking in chrome 68. but code is working fine in version 67. I have faced same issue in Firefox as well. but i fixed it by disabling the multi process in Mozilla Firefox config file. Do anyone know setting in flags or setting. from which i can fix. this issue in version 68. I have checked the code it works fine for IE11 also. Urgent help required.